# How to avoid sign extending bit mask in Java?

Tags: java, unsigned, signed, bitmask

My bit masks are bytes, and I'd like to keep them exactly as they are, but I think they're sign extended.  I don't care if the byte is considered positive or negative, as long as it has the same bits set.  I just spent a few hours debugging my code, and then I found I'm only having a problem with my byte bit masks when they happen to be negative, it took a while to find out.  I can't be the only one who's had a problem with this.  Is there a way to make a byte behave as if it was unsigned?

Comment: You can use a larger integral type.

Comment: You should probably post the code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have right-shift in your code? do you use '>>' instead of '>>>'? There is your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I use >>, so you say I should use >>>?  I'll check it up.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want a byte to sign extend when you use it in arithmetic (or bitwise) operators, you need to explicitly bitwise-and it with 0xFF. It looks slightly ugly but is unavoidable if what you have is a `byte` (and hopefully a decent JIT will be able to recognize the idiom and make efficient code out of it anyway).

Comment: I guess that's what I have to do.